# Blueberry flowers turning black after pollination

Tags: flowers, pollination, blueberries

As you can see in the picture the stem? parts of the flower is turning black after the flower dried up and fell off. They are also fall of easily when I touch them. My blueberry flowers are being pollinated via brush because I live in a apartment. The plant looks healthy perfectly green with no yellowing or browning so I really don’t know what to do. Is there a reason for this? Is it common? [image: black stem of a blueberry flower]

Comment: Welcome! Just to understand better: how many plants do you have and are they indoors or outdoors? Do you happen to know the cultivar?

Comment: The plant was bought for me by a family member so I don’t know who grew it, also I only have one plant at the moment I plan to get more

Comment: Thank you! With “cultivar” I meant the “name”, not the person who grew or bred the plant. But it’s not crucial.

Comment: The type is “pink lemonade” sorry for the confusion